# error when booting

Tags: boot, grub2

Recently my laptop has been unable to boot, I have been having hard drive problems over three past few weeks but I would like to know if I need a new hard drive or not.

When booting I get,

```
Error: unknown filesystem
Entering rescue mode...
Grubrescue>
```

I have tried to fix it by following online guides, knew of Wichita told me to do this,

```
# on the grub shell do:
set root=(hd0,6)
set prefix=(hd0,6)/boot/grub
insmod normal
normal
# boot into the system, then in the shell do
sudo update-grub
sudo grub-install /dev/sda
```

This failed after `insmod normal` and it stated `error: unknown filesystem`

I need some advice about if it's a hard drive fault or if it's fixable and if so how?

Comment: you have to run grub-install before you run grub-update

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest repairing grub from a live disk. After you login run the following commands:

```
sudo fdisk -l /dev/sda
```

This will output your partitions to see which one contains your Ubuntu OS. Mine is on /dev/sda6 so I will use that as an example, however, yours may be /dev/sda1 or something else.

```
sudo mount /dev/sda6 /
sudo chroot /
sudo update-grub
sudo reboot
```

If this does not work, you may need to install grub again before you update grub. If this is the case, boot a live disk and run the following commands:

```
sudo fdisk -l /dev/sda
```

This will tell you the partition you need to use in the following commands, again, I will use /dev/sda6 as an example, however, yours may be /dev/sda1 or something else.

```
sudo mount /dev/sda6 /mnt
sudo grub-install --root-directory=/mnt/ /dev/sda
```

Notice the last command uses /dev/sda with no number, this installs grub to the MBR. A successful installation will report no errors.

Next, don't forget to change /dev/sda6 to the corresponding partition.

```
sudo mount /dev/sda6 /
sudo chroot /
sudo update-grub
sudo reboot
```